# 301 redirect wrongly applied. Is it ok to change to a new redirect?

Tags: redirect

I'm taking over a website which recently had its entire urls changed. Instead of applying a 301 redirect from each old page to its new corresponding page, the entire site was redirected to the new home page.

Would it hurt to undo this 301 redirect and have the correct ones applied instead?

Thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck asking this question over at serverfault.com instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will hurt.  Your new changes will only be applied to new requests of the old site though.